# Which SQL Date format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Which date format does T-SQL use? Does it rely on the system date? How can I be sure that my parameters are passed on correctly regardless of system date format. This question comes because of error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

The SQL script in part:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sz_pipeline04_pipelUpdte_inventory] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@myFixDte datetime,
@doInsert bit   
AS   
BEGIN
```

The calling c# code:

```
    public static DataTable GridInventory(string strdProcedureName, DateTime fixDate, bool execInsertYN)
    {
        DataTable dtbl_inventory = null;
        try
        {
            dtbl_inventory = new DataTable();

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cls_connRegistry.GetConnStrFull()))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(strdProcedureName, conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            })
            {

                command.Parameters.Add("@myFixDte", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(fixDate.ToShortDateString());
                command.Parameters.Add("@doInsert", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = execInsertYN;

                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                dtbl_inventory.Load(dr);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception datawalile)
        { dtbl_inventory = null; }

        return dtbl_inventory;
    }
```

edited question.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187928.aspx) link about converting varchar to data type

Comment: @N.Molderf thanks. However, the issue here is not about the date formats in SQL but rather how I would know / get the current date FORMAT in use at SQL or alternatively ONE function that would work EVERY TIME with any SQL date format. So I am sending the arguments in my c# application and the GUI date control changes date format as per system date format - fine: I would have thought SQL follows same logic but apparently not - how do I pass those arguments regardless.

Comment: Ideally, if you're accessing SQL from another language, use *parameters* to pass the data as a `DateTime` value, let the language bindings/data access library deal with the translation to SQL Server's `datetime` type and avoid passing it as a *string* at all. Formatting issues only arise when you pass the value around as a *string* rather than the appropriate type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : well I have tried back & forth (date or string params), it fails. This is my script:

Comment: If you want to show more code, please [tag:edit] your question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever                                                               CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sz_pipeline04_pipelUpdte_inventory] 
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
--@myFixDte datetime,
--@doInsert bit

AS
BEGIN

Comment: I had to comment out the arguments because of rules here ...

Comment: As I said, please [edit] your question because you cannot format code in comments. Also, I was talking about the *calling* end of things, not the procedure - are you just calling this procedure from an SSMS window or are you calling it from some other (non-SQL) piece of code? If the latter, there's almost certainly a way to provide parameters *there*, rather than constructing the procedure call as a string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why you didnt tell as above c# datetime, here is a simple example for you how to solve this problem in your case it will be something like this

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

or this one

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

second one is a default

Comment: this assumes I will passing on a string parameter onto sql. I'm passing the datetime format. Which is best?

Comment: in your case you dont know you datetime on sql side so this solution will be better for you, just try how does it work

Comment: @Chagbert Is it possible that the date could actually be outside that range? Does it come from user input? If the answer to either of these questions is yes, then you should always check - otherwise you're leaving your application prone to error.

Comment: thanks Molderf - this advice made me to finally  use a string parameter which I immediately convert in SQL procedure - see answer to @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas

Comment: @Chagbert - this is unfortunately not proper solution. While dealing with dates, you should always use date[time] SQL parameters - makes your procedure independent on current culture or any date format (unless your database contains dates as strings, which is another problem entirely). And - SQL date formats are not yyyymmdd kind of ones - SQL date format is some kind of binary representation of date, depend on exact format used.

Comment: I guess I can not be helped. It is difficult from these posts to know which is a fact about SQL date format ... I would just love a simple efficient robust answer please. How can I pass date parameters into SQL independent of system clock format

Comment: `mm` is minutes, not months.  Case matters.

Comment: @Chagbert - the main problem is that you're still convinced that `datetime`s *have* a format. "What colour are `int`s in SQL Server?" is a simple *question* but it doesn't have a "simple efficient robust answer" because it's being asked based on a false assumption (that `int`s have colours, or `datetime`s have a format). A `datetime` is a floating point number where the integral part is the number of days since `1900-01-01` and the fractional part is how far through that day. But you don't need to know this because ADO.Net knows how to translate `DateTime` parameters into `datetime`s.

Comment: @Chagbert - and formatting *issues* only rear their head when, despite the fact that both C# and SQL Server understand `datetime` data, you insist on converting them into *strings* and back again.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the insight - I really did follow your advice earlier on and did not convert the datetime parameters I receive from the control. However, I noted this works fine if my control is a Windows 'DatetTimePicker' - and it does not in my case where I am using a DevExpress 'DateEdit' control. In fact, this is how I read this DevX control:  DateTime.Parse(this.dtpEnd.EditValue.ToString());

Answer (score 2):

The code you've now posted looks correct - except for one thing:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@myFixDte", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(fixDate.ToShortDateString());
```

As I've said in the comments, issues only come up around formatting when you convert to strings. So just do:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@myFixDte", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fixDate;
```

`DateTime`s (C#) and `datetime` (T-SQL) don't *have* a format. You get formatting issues when you convert them into strings. In their native representation, they're usually just a count of a number of events (ticks, milliseconds, etc) since some fixed point in the past. ADO.Net knows how to convert a `DateTime` into a SQL Server `datetime`.

If you have remaining conversion issues, it's in code you've not yet shown. But it will, again, be because you're converting away from the correct data type (`datetime`) and using strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid DATETIME format `DD-MM-YYYY`.

You can use **[CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)** It in following:

```
DECLARE @myFixDte DATETIME
SET @myFixDte = CONVERT(DATE, N'30-12-2012', 104)
SELECT @myFixDte
```

Or you can SET It without converting in other format like `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Check "V" in top left of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@myFixDte = convert(datetime, '30-12-2012', 105)
```

And check the link provided by @N.Molderf

Comment: see above. I think the format is not only the order of day, month & year but also the separator ("-" or "." or "/"): how do I know which is in use?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server recognizes one format always in same way, regardless which culture it using, and that format is `YYYYMMDD`.

So you can always use your dates in format `20120202` or `20151225`, and SQL Server will parse that parameter using same mask.

Comment: you are right - I did't know then but after much Googling and SQL documentation I realised.